# Water flow sensor

Tags: arduino, sensor, flow-sensor

I want to use a water flow sensor to check the water flow in my laser cutter. I could find a lot of code for that but I can't understand the logic. I'm new to Arduino.

This is what I understand so far
For every 1 liter/min sensor will produce 4.5 pulses. (In some code it's 7.5). So by counting total pulses and dividing it by 4.5 I could gate flow rate in liter/min.

But the equation explained in the code is

```
Pulse frequency (Hz) = 7.5Q, Q is flow rate in Litres/minute
Flow Rate (Litres/hour) = (Pulse frequency x 60 min) / 7.5Q
```

why there is a Q in the denominator? I thought this may be an error from the programmer but several codes have Q in their denominator.

eg: http://www.electroschematics.com/12145/working-with-water-flow-sensors-arduino/

```
 l_hour = (flow_frequency * 60 / 7.5); // (Pulse frequency x 60 min) / 7.5Q = flowrate in L/hour
```

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=8548.0

```
 Calc = (NbTopsFan * 60 / 7.5); //(Pulse frequency x 60) / 7.5Q, = flow rate
```

But then I come across several other codes.
eg :
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Flow-Meter/blob/master/Adafruit_FlowMeter.pde

It uses the following logic

```
// if a plastic sensor use the following calculation
// Sensor Frequency (Hz) = 7.5 * Q (Liters/min)
// Liters = Q * time elapsed (seconds) / 60 (seconds/minute)
// Liters = (Frequency (Pulses/second) / 7.5) * time elapsed (seconds) / 60
// Liters = Pulses / (7.5 * 60)
```

I don't understand this formula either. Can anyone help me to understand these?
Also what the output of this code. Is it giving flow rate (liter/min or liter/ second) or is it giving flow (liter)?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you already asked your question and had it answered over on the [Arduino Forums](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=405782.5)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will change dependant on which sensor you use. For the purpose of this question I will use the example given, however if you want accurate information please provide us with the number of the actual sensor you plan to use.

Q is the unit for volumetric flow rate, it is in Litres/min.

```
Pulse frequency (Hz) = 7.5Q, Q is flow rate in Litres/minute
```

This first snippet of code is basically saying that the sensor will produce 7.5 pulses per second for every 1 litre/minute of water flowing. The reason why different examples use a different number as opposed to 7.5 is due to the different sensors they are using.

```
// Sensor Frequency (Hz) = 7.5 * Q (Liters/min)
// Liters = Q * time elapsed (seconds) / 60 (seconds/minute)
// Liters = (Frequency (Pulses/second) / 7.5) * time elapsed (seconds) / 60
// Liters = Pulses / (7.5 * 60)
```

Sensor frequency is the number of pulses per second coming from the water flow sensor.

The last 3 equations are basically all the same but rearranged, it is the conversion of pulses to their physical counterpart (Changing the number of pulses into the flow rate in litres/hour)

\$Pulses = 7.5 \times Q\$
\$Q = Pulses / 7.5\$ (This is flow rate in Litres/min)
\$Q = Pulses / (7.5\times60)\$ (This is flow rate in Litres/hour)

This is only for instantaneous readings, if your laser has a constantly changing rate of water flow then you will need to do a bit more work.

Comment: @Athul Notice how they use 'Q' in their comments, but in their actual equations they omit the Q. As to why the first one has the Q doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Flow rate =Q--->
**Pulse frequency (Hz) = 7.5Q, Q is flow rate in Litres/minute**  then
**Flow Rate (Litres/min) = (Pulse frequency ) / 7.5**.
so**Flow Rate (Litres/hour) = (Pulse frequency x 60 min) / 7.5**
But if you look at the first set of equations that i posted

**Flow Rate (Litres/hour) = (Pulse frequency x 60 min) / 7.5Q**. Why is there a Q in denomintor

Isn't it mathematically incorrect?

Comment: @Athul Yes, as they also said over on the arduino forums. The first set of equations which uses Q is incorrect. The other sets of equations are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fully understand the original question, something does not seem to make sense in the equations.

I deployed a Seeed YF-B6 flow meter which according to [Seeed](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Water-Flow-Sensor-YF-B6-p-2883.html) has a Frequency of "F=(6.6*Q)Q=L/MIN±3%". Given the equation Q = F/6.6, I expected that a flow of 1L/min would produce 6.6 pulses. When I used this in my code, I was getting ridiculous flow rates like ±300L/min, which was impossible for the little 10L/min solar circulation pump I was measuring.

After much reading, I think the best clue is the statement on this [website](https://www.tinytronics.nl/shop/en/sensors/liquid/yf-b6-water-flow-sensor-brass-g3-4): "The output of the sensor gives **6.6 pulses per second** with a duty cycle of approximately 50% for every liter of liquid that passes through it per minute".
So the Seeed figures actually refer to 6.6 pulses per second for 60 seconds (396 pulses) at a flow rate of 1L/min.

Another way to deploy the factor in code is to divide 1 litre by 396 pulses (6.6 pulses * 60 seconds), which equates to each pulse measuring 0.0025L of liquid flow. Multiply the number of pulses measured by this factor and then scale this to the time you are measuring over. Of course this factor is slightly different for each model of flow meter.

In summary, I believe the confusion comes in with some code using the volume of liquid per pulse as the base factor, while Seeed Studio includes a 1 second frequency dimension in their specifications. For Seeed flow meters you have to remember to scale up that one second factor to a minute if your equations are based on the volume of liquid per pulse. Otherwise the original equation that is common in lots of the example code, works just fine: flowRate = ((1000.0 / (millis() - oldTime)) * pulseCount) / calibrationFactor.